# Type Parameter is not within bounds

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to create a `JLabel` with an index number. So, I created a class `indexedJLabel` extending `JLabel`. When I try to create an `ArrayList` of the new object I get the error: type parameter `IndexedJLabel` is not within its bound. Please see my code below.

```
public class IndexedJLabel extends JLabel
{
    private int index = -1;
    public IndexedJLabel()
    {
        super();
        index = -1;
    }
}
```

Creating an array of `IndexedJLabel`

```
private static ArrayList<IndexedJLabel> primaryPanelLabels = new ArrayList<IndexedJLabel>(20);
```

Comment: Compile error or runtime error?

Comment: I'm not getting a compile error when I plug your code into Eclipse. Are you sure you've pasted all the relevant pieces?

Comment: Just realized I forgot to include the swing package in the IndexedJLabel class. Doh! Thanks for checking out my code.

Answer (score 0):

private int index;

You don't set a value explicitly unless it's static until the constructor is called.